# unable to fetch data from twitter using flume. Face an error java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Tags: hadoop, flume

```
17/04/10 22:55:57 ERROR flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: localhost:50070/user/hduser/twitter_data/FlumeData.1491845142613.tmp
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:463)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: localhost:50070/user/hduser/twitter_data/FlumeData.1491845142613.tmp
```

Comment: Some additional context showing how you got the error would be helpful

Comment: A flume config would be useful :)